# Passing data between viewControllers in MVVM

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

I am having trouble with passing data from my `collectionViewController` to `detailViewController`.

I am trying to learn `MVVM` now and it's kinda confusing to me. In `MVC` it's quite straight forward but in `MVVM` I am having problems with this.

My `MainViewModel`:

```
struct CatViewModel {

    let catImage: String

    // Dependency Injection

    init(catImage: CatModel) {
        self.catImage = catImage.url
    }

    func detailViewModel(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> DetailsViewModel 
    {
        return DetailsViewModel(catImage: catImage)
    }

}
```

My `detailViewModel`:

```
struct DetailsViewModel {

    let catImage: String

}
```

My `collectionViewCell` class:

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewCell: CustomImageView!

    var catViewModel: CatViewModel! {
        didSet {
            setUpCellImage()
        }
    }

    func setUpCellImage() {
        if let cellImageUrl = catViewModel?.catImage {
            imageViewCell.loadImageUsingUrlString(urlString: cellImageUrl)
        }
}
```

So how should I now pass data from my `detailViewController`? In `MVC` it would be simple, but can't find a proper answer/way how to do it in `MVVM`.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let destVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as! DetailViewController

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destVC, animated: true)
    }
```

My `detilViewController` class:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var largeImageView: UIImageView!

    var detailViewModel = [DetailsViewModel]()
    var detailImage = UIImage()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.largeImageView.image = detailImage
    }
}
```

Comment: It's trivial, just create a object on your detailViewController class and use `destVc.object = value` on `didSelectItemAt`. If you need more help, please post your detailViewController class.

Comment: Have updated my code and added detailViewController class

Comment: On `didSelect` you can get collection cell and from that you will have `CatViewModal`. Now you can pass whole model to deatilviewcontroller or image url

Comment: where are you array data?

Comment: You must have to have `CatViewModel` or `catImage` property in `DetailViewController` then you can assign value to that property

Comment: Yes, there is catImage variable in detailViewController

Comment: Please refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45463336/pass-data-to-uiviewcontroller-under-McMahon-pattern